# Disabling and deselecting radio button after another is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a simple numeric system converter using Python and I'm using Tkinter for the GUI. I'm trying to make it work like this:

1. User presses "Decimal" radio on "From:" side, "Decimal" radio on "To:" side gets disabled
2. User presses "Octal" on "To:" side, nothing changes
3. User presses "Octal" on "From:" side, "Octal" radio on "To:" side gets disabled and deselected

But so far, it works like this:

1. User presses "Decimal" radio on "From:" side, "Decimal" radio on "To:" side gets disabled
2. User presses "Octal" on "To:" side, nothing changes
3. User presses "Octal" on "From:" side, "Octal" radio on "To:" side gets disabled but stays selected

What changes should I make for this to work as intended?

My code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

fromsel = IntVar()
tosel = IntVar()

def disable_button():
    fr = fromsel.get()
    tbin_radio.config(state = DISABLED if fr == 2 else NORMAL)
    toct_radio.config(state = DISABLED if fr == 8 else NORMAL)
    tdec_radio.config(state = DISABLED if fr == 10 else NORMAL)
    thex_radio.config(state = DISABLED if fr == 16 else NORMAL)

fromlabel = Label(root, text="From:", justify = LEFT, anchor = W)

fbin_radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Binary", variable = fromsel, value = 2, command = disable_button)
foct_radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Octal", variable = fromsel, value = 8, command = disable_button)
fdec_radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Decimal", variable = fromsel, value = 10, command = disable_button)
fhex_radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Hexadecimal", variable = fromsel,  value = 16, command = disable_button)

fromentry = Entry(root)

tolabel = Label(root, text="To:")

tbin_radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Binary", variable = tosel, value = 1)
toct_radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Octal", variable = tosel, value = 2)
tdec_radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Decimal", variable = tosel, value = 3)
thex_radio = Radiobutton(root, text="Hexadecimal", variable = tosel,  value = 4)

toentry = Entry(root)

fromlabel.grid(row = 0)

fbin_radio.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
foct_radio.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
fdec_radio.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
fhex_radio.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

fromentry.grid(row = 2, columnspan = 4)

tolabel.grid(row = 3)

tbin_radio.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
toct_radio.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
tdec_radio.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
thex_radio.grid(row = 4, column = 3)

toentry.grid(row = 5, columnspan = 4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I know this is not a functional example, but I'm still working on this and I'm stuck on the radio buttons part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear `tosel` if both "from" and "to" are the same:

```py
def disable_button():
    fr = fromsel.get()
    tbin_radio.config(state = DISABLED if fr == 2 else NORMAL)
    toct_radio.config(state = DISABLED if fr == 8 else NORMAL)
    tdec_radio.config(state = DISABLED if fr == 10 else NORMAL)
    thex_radio.config(state = DISABLED if fr == 16 else NORMAL)
    mappings = ((2,1), (8,2), (10,3), (16,4))
    if (fr,tosel.get()) in mappings:
        # both "from" and "to" are the same, so clear "to" selection
        tosel.set(None)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That actually works exactly as intended :D